Is there a port of Rick Almendinger's stereonet program to android?
I was looking around for the stereonet program I used in college and found that Almendinger has an iOS version. Is there an android version?

Why don't you ask the maker of that program?

I looked at his website. He has a port to iOS. Someone else appears to have an android version but it doesn't seem to be associated with Almendinger's website.

I meant ask the person!

Yep, I'll send him an email

Okay I emailed. But I'm not hopeful. His contact page is here:  https://www.rickallmendinger.net/contact-me, as it says, he had >11,000 unread emails so he may not get back to me

I emailed Almendinger. He responded that he doesn't work with android. He Is not aware of any port.
